# Search a model's reference's/foreign_key's attribute (in rails using SQLite3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am trying to perform a search function on a table

```
# my controller EntriesController.rb
  def index
    @entries = Entry.all
    @entries = Entry.search(params[:search])
    @entry = current_user.entries.build if logged_in?
  end
```

I was able to implement a search bar using self.search method in my model

```
# app/models/entry.rb
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :sample, :charge, :need_by, :file_format, :scan_type, presence: true

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('created_at LIKE :search OR sample LIKE :search OR 
             need_by LIKE :search OR scan_type LIKE :search', 
             search: "%#{search}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works so far, but the entry model references the user model by user_id. I would like the search to be able to search the user model as well. So I tried adding this to the search method in entry.rb

```
if search
  where('user.name LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
end
```

SQLite3 obviously shot me an error saying the column, "user.name" doesn't exist. I know it doesn't exist, but is there any way I can access it without having to use something like Ransack? Or should I just learn how to use a search gem?

Here's the full exception

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.name: SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE (user.name LIKE '%asdf%' OR created_at LIKE '%asdf%' OR sample LIKE '%asdf%' OR need_by LIKE '%asdf%' OR scan_type LIKE '%asdf%') AND "entries"."scanned" = ?  ORDER BY "entries"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Currently, I am populating the table in question by using:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= entry.created_at.strftime("%Y %m %d") %></td>
    <td><%= entry.user.name %></td>
    <td><!-- other entry stuff --></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

TL;DR, i'd like to make entry.user.name a searchable term.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to have a search function inside the related model too.

That way you could just say

```
user.search(search)
```

And get your list back in that manner.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that if I'm using the Entry model to generate my list? I added some details into the original post showing how I populate my table.